# validation is not working in firebase recycler adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'am applying a validation in which I'am getting all the tokens in list  from database and then in onBindviewHolder Iam applying Foreach loop in which I'am matching all the token with the current user token and if token matches that item view should not be shown in recyclerview 
Here Iam getting the list of tokens :

```
for (DataSnapshot parent : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String token;
                    token = parent.getKey();
                    tokenList.add(token);
                }
```

And in here showing the list :

```
 for (String tokens : tokenList) {

                    if (bloodGroupMatched.contains(bloodGroup) && !tokens.equals(userId)) {

                        holder.name.setText(profiles.getName());
                        holder.type.setText(userType);
                        holder.distance.setText(dist + " km");
                        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        params.setMargins(10, 5, 5, 10);
                        holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    } else {

                        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
                    }

                }
```

while showing the list if I toast the tokens the loop doesn't end and its keep showing the tokens  from start when list ends and don't show anything in recyclerview .I want to show the list of user except does who doesn't meet the criteria.And if I remove this check "!tokens.equals(userId)" and remove the loop its start working fine but I have to apply this validation also
[image]

Iam getting these node and and which ever node matched the currently login user node I dont want to show his details.
And this is my whole function where Iam using this logic :

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Profiles, DonarViewHolder>(model) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DonarViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Profiles profiles) {

                ArrayList<String> bloodGroupMatched = new ArrayList<>();
                bloodGroupMatched.addAll(profiles.getMatched_bloodGroups());

                for (String tokens : tokenList) {

                    if (bloodGroupMatched.contains(bloodGroup) && !tokens.equals(userId)) {

                        holder.name.setText(profiles.getName());
                        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        params.setMargins(10, 5, 5, 10);
                        holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    } else {

                        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
                    }
                }
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public DonarViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_donar_view_holder, parent, false);
                return new DonarViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter.startListening();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you show your database structure and elaborate your requirements rather than asking for solution of your problems in code? May be this will solve in a convenient that rather than your approach

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this by changing my logic in **onBindViewHolder**
**I removed foreach loop and started matching userId with tokenlist position**

```
   ArrayList<String> bloodGroupMatched = new ArrayList<>();
        bloodGroupMatched.addAll(profiles.getMatched_bloodGroups());


        if (bloodGroupMatched.contains(bloodGroup) && !userId.equals(tokenList.get(position))){

            holder.name.setText(profiles.getName());
            holder.type.setText(userType);
            holder.distance.setText(dist + " km");
            holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(10, 5, 5, 10);
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
        } else {

            holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
        }
```